# Visual Studio 2017 V15.5.2 Wont install Entity Framework through NuGet

Tags: entity-framework

Ever since upgrading to VS2017 Version 15.5.2, I can no longer add the EF to new projects (I'm running Windows 10):

```
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(3007) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(3014) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(3021) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(3028) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(3035) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The term 'Get-ExecutionPolicy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
Install failed. Rolling back...
```

Then, in the projects directory an unreadable folder object is contained in the ....\packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\content.  The folder is net40 and can only get deleted if I boot into safe mode.

Anyone know how to workaround this issue in Windows 10?

UPDATE:

[image: Powershell Version]

Comment: What is your PS execution policy?  (`Get-ExecutionPolicy -list`)  Are you able to run that command?

Comment: Yes, it is `RemoteSigned`.  I have changed it to `Undefined` and it still fails.  I should have mentioned that, sorry.

Comment: Might be related:  https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2686  That link suggests you need to install an update.